# Is it acceptable to commit API Keys and .env files to a private business repo?

Tags: git, security, github, environment-variables

I did a search and surprisingly found no answer. Right now we don't commit our API Keys/`.env` file on a repo that a growing team of 4 is working on. Whenever we change something, like say, a DB Password, we send it out to each other via Slack.

This seems pointless considering our repo is Private, not forkable, and is only given access to by employees.

The only ways I could see this going wrong are:

1. Employee accidentally published the repo publicly. Though this would be a disaster anyway since our whole codebase would be public, so I fail to see how changing keys and passwords would be our biggest concern.
2. An employee account is compromised. See above ^ (We also enforce MFA as a consolation).
3. GitHub themselves are breached, which again, we have bigger problems (and most software companies).
4. Insert vague Microsoft conspiracy here

Is there a reason we should continue this practice or can we just commit our `.env` file?

Comment: This should probably closed as it is opiniated, but think about this. Someone manages to get access to your repo. That sucks, all your code is breached and out on the streets. If you've committed api keys and the like, not just your code but everything that has to do with your app is out on the streets. Your entire S3 storage, all your email accounts, all your Stripe information, etc etc etc. TL;DR please don't commit your keys. Just please don't. https://www.zdnet.com/article/over-100000-github-repos-have-leaked-api-or-cryptographic-keys/

Comment: Most if not all Git-repository managers allow adding environment variables. You can use these variable both for pipelines and for sharing with each other. Win win.

Comment: 5. An employee conspiracy: someone who has legal access has cloned the repo with API keys and passwords. Later she was booted. Now your keys and passwords are in hands of non-loyal ex-employee.

Comment: They would have been anyway since they need those to run the Repo Locally and connect to the DB. PAsswords get swapped when employees are hired.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/git-secrets-api-keys

Answer (score 0):

We use [ENVKEY](https://www.envkey.com/) to solve for this now.